# React Redux immutability cheat sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently learning react with redux and know that immutability is a key component of these technologies, yet am struggling to fully understand how to implement it.

As such I was wondering if there were any cheat sheets for react/redux immutability out there?

If not, what were your preferred methods of implementing immutability in your react redux applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By its very nature, Redux application state is already immutable. Redux destroys your application state and rebuilds a brand new one every time you fire off an action (which triggers a reducer that rebuilds state). So there is no cheatsheet for making Redux work immutably because it already does.

You might be getting confused because there are libraries that deal with immutable structures, like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), and there are packages for incorporating those into Redux such as [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable). While using Immutable.js would mean that your individual pieces of state are saved as Immutable structures, this is not necessary to make your application state immutable because the fundamental nature of your application state is already immutable with or without a library. Using Immutable.js with Redux is mostly useful for things like quickly comparing props passed down from the state to see if they have changed so you can bypass re-renders.

Comment: It was the 'individual pieces of state' you mention which I was actually referring to. I should of been clearer, apologies!

I think to answer my own question I was looking for the following...

Avoid array mutations using concat(), slice(), and ...spread and avoid object mutations using ...spread.

I suppose I should do further research into each of these as I would rather use as few external libraries as possible. Would be keen to get opinions on that though!

Comment: @Thomas_Hoadley Ah so you are referring to methods used in reducer functions to rebuild state immutably? Your comment has more-or-less answered that actually (i.e. use concat(), slice(), ...spread). Another one to keep in mind is Object.assign(). My personal preference is the spread operator as I use Babel and I find it to be the most clean and clear. As mentioned above, Immutable.js is not really needed for Redux, I mainly use it b/c I have large deeply-nested objects in state & it is way faster to compare when they are Immutable structures in `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Comment: Okay great thank you for the help! I will try to stick with the basic methods and resort to immutable.js only if required! Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Redux` doesn't guarantee immutability out-of-the-box. You could easily return a mutated state in your reducer, and Redux won't complain. That said the ethos of Redux is to generate new state on each action change, but the implementation details are up to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog post about this! You can find it here: http://www.curbitssoftware.com/2017/08/25/react-redux-immutable-update-cheat-sheet/

One thing that is really important when working with Redux is that you should never mutate (change directly) your state. Instead you should always return a copy of the state that you change (a common misconception is that you need to copy/clone everything, read more [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/758#issuecomment-141967817) and [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/688087202312491008). This means you need to learn new ways of working with arrays, changing the property of objects and so on. To make this easier we wanted to share our own cheat sheet / recipe book for the most common cases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found this series of videos really useful regarding this topic:

https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

It's free and recommended from within the React docs.  There are specific, short sections that describe how to write reducer functions that to not modify the existing state.  They discuss using `Object.assign()`, ES6 `...` spread operator, etc.

One particular strategy I found useful is testing using `deepFreeze` on the original state to ensure that your reducer functions do not modify it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-freeze-strict

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that caught me out is that while you return the `state` object from the reducer, there is nothing in redux to enforce you simply mutating the previous state, accidentally or otherwise.

I was returning a copy of the updated state with `Object.assign({}, state, {key: 'new value'})`, BUT if your state is not flat i.e.

```
state => {foo: {bar: {baz: 'some value'}}}
```

the nested objects will be **referenced** instead of copied since `Object.assign()` is **not** a deep copy, and it becomes very easy to hold onto stale state, or accidentally nuke nested properties by overwriting higher-up values.

Immutable.js and other libraries will help you with utilities to solve this problem. Or you could just keep the state flat like the redux docs recommend. You could copy each nested property individually, but this adds a ton of cruft to the reducer.

Comment: THIS IS BY DESIGN!

To keep things performant, parts of the state that don't change should be passed to the new state by reference so that you aren't rebuilding the whole state tree.  Ideally, the reducer makes a minimal amount of new state, and only that part relevant to the action.  This new piece of state is then incorporated into the whole state tree by the reducers "above" this one.